# How to display a table with Matlab Publish

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab [publish](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/publishing-matlab-code.html) to create reports:

```
% Main function
publish('weeklyReport');

% weeklyReport.m

%% First Section
% This is the first section.

T = array2table(rand(5,3));
```

How can I subsequently publish this to the report? If I do not include the semicolon `;` then it is shown. However, is there another way to force append it?

Comment: `disp(T)` should work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Wolfie in the comments, you can easily achieve this by `disp(T)`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use writetable function:

```
writetable(T,[fname '.xlsx'])
```